# Captcha for a small project using only JavaScript

Tags: javascript, captcha

So I started working on something which isn't anything to be published online, just for exhibition purpose.

I wanted to know if there's a way to have a Captcha which isn't static using only JavaScript, as currently I don't want to use PHP or anything else.

For now, I have a code which uses a static image as a Captcha.

Comment: Save a bunch of captcha images in files, then load one of them randomly into the document.

Comment: That'd be good, thank you! I'm also curious, is there another way of doing this? Like without preset files.

Comment: Search for node.js captcha code. It may contain JS for creating captcha images, you could run the same thing on the client.

Comment: @Barmar but I have no clue as to what node.js is

Comment: node.js is JavaScript running on the server.

Comment: use google recaptcha

Comment: That is easy to use.

Comment: @Barmar and what is the "server"?

Comment: Thre is no server. I was just suggesting that you take code that's designed to run on the server,and run it on the client instead.

Comment: @Barmar I'll definitely look into it. Thank you for the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this function to generate and change the Captcha onload.

```
function ChangeCaptcha() {
    var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; 
    // You can include special characters by adding them to the string above, for eg: chars += "@#?<>";

    var string_length = 6; // This is the length of the Captcha    
    var ChangeCaptcha = '';
    for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) {
        var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
        ChangeCaptcha += chars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
    }

    document.getElementById('randomfield').value = ChangeCaptcha; // Final step which changes the field value to the Captcha produced
}
```

Please make sure that you Google your questions first before posting them. I'd made a video on this 4 years ago which you can find [**here**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2EsiEcu7v0A)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Sorry for not Googling, I'll make sure I do so next time.

Answer (score 0):

There is no sense in having "client side only captcha", as it will provide no protection for submitting and processing data by the server. It can only protect from a (big) fraction of human users, while - possibly - you main problem is the bots, who will have no issues continuing spamming your backends.